# Color coding Tasks list by due date in SharePoint Designer 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

Using Sharepoint 2010, how do I color code the Task due dates so the row can turn red when the due date is in 5 days?
....green color for when task due date is in 10 days?

My requirements are a bit different than the questions that have already been answered. Let me explain:

1. For Tasks list--The condition criteria (using SP Designer 2010) has to be based on due dates so the row automatically changes color(green or red) based on how long is left before they are due (5 days vs. 10 days)

Comment: Please search the site before asking. This question has been asked and aswered before.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done in a couple of steps:

```
1.Create a calculated column that will calculate the difference between due date and current date and based on the output, a color is assigned to that column 
2.Create another calculated column to output the styling (html/css) of the color coding
3-Add content editor web part with javascript code to rebuild the UI based on the value of the calculated column.
```

This is based on this blog post:
 https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/333/sharepoint-2007-and-2010--color-coding-custom-lists-and-tasks